# Color shape according to its text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with several shapes which have text strings, I'd like to color those shapes based on its text. Here is the code I have that for now it doesn't work as expected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim shp As Shape, r As Long, g As Long, b As Long, NormScale As String

With ActiveSheet
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        With shp.TextFrame
            Select Case NormScale
            Case "N"
                r = 255
                g = 0
                b = 0
            Case "P"
                r = 128
                g = 128
                b = 128
            End Select
        End With
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next shp
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't work as expected`? Does the program crash? Only apply one colour? Doesn't apply any colour?

Comment: It colors black all shapes in the sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot to read the text:

```
Sub Mike()

Dim shp As Shape, r As Long, g As Long, b As Long, NormScale As String

With ActiveSheet
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        With shp.TextFrame
            NormScale = .Characters.Text
            Select Case NormScale
            Case "N"
                r = 255
                g = 0
                b = 0
            Case "P"
                r = 128
                g = 128
                b = 128
            End Select
        End With
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next shp
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To exclude specific *Shapes* from the process, we must first **identify** then:

```
Sub WhatDoWeHave()
Dim shp As Shape
With ActiveSheet
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        MsgBox shp.Type & vbCrLf & shp.Name
    Next shp
End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

This version will exclude *Shapes* whose *Name* begins with "Picture"

```
Sub Mike()

Dim shp As Shape, r As Long, g As Long, b As Long, NormScale As String

With ActiveSheet
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        If InStr(shp.Name, "Picture") = 0 Then
            With shp.TextFrame
                NormScale = .Characters.Text
                Select Case NormScale
                Case "N"
                    r = 255
                    g = 0
                    b = 0
                Case "P"
                    r = 128
                    g = 128
                    b = 128
                End Select
            End With
            shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(r, g, b)
        End If
    Next shp
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Displays error "Object doesn't support the property or method".

Comment: @Mike  That means there are are some *Shapes* on the worksheet that don't support *Text.Characters.*  I tested the code with **AutoShapes**

Comment: I also have pictures in the sheet. Can I exclude them or is there some workaround?

Comment: Picture 1, Picture 2, Picture 3 and Picture 4 must be excluded. Those are the names.